# FULL OUTER JOIN with Rails 6 ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, outer-join, full-outer-join

I am modeling an app with messages and notifications as follows (simplified):

```rb
# db/schema.rb
    create_table :messages do |t|
      ...
    end

    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.references :message, index: true, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.references :recipient, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }, null: false
      t.datetime :read_at
      ...
    end
```

Models:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord; end
class Message < ApplicationRecord; end
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :message
end
```

In this simplified example:

- the messages table holds the actual messages (e.g title, text, images, ...)
- the notifications table keeps track of which user has read which message
- all messages are for all users (e.g. system-wide "announcements"). To be generalized to let messages target specific users.

I am looking for the cleanest (most Rails-like) and most performant way to load a user's notifications and related messages, while ensuring that all messages are loaded even if no notification has yet been created in DB for this user. This is to avoid needing to create as many notification rows in DB as there are users every time a new message is published. A row is added to the notifications table only when the user has read the message (storing the `read_at` value).

I managed to achieve it using this SQL:

```rb
  # user.rb

  def notifications
    unsanitised_sql = <<-SQL
      SELECT 
        :user_id AS recipient_id, m.id as message_id, n.read_at, n.created_at, n.updated_at,
        m.text, ...
      FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM notifications 
        WHERE recipient_id = :user_id
      ) n
      FULL OUTER JOIN messages m
      ON (message_id = m.id)
    SQL

    ActiveRecord::Base
      .connection
      .select_all(ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql [ unsanitised_sql, { user_id: id } ])
      .map do |row|

      Notification.new(
        recipient_id: row['recipient_id'],
        message_id: row['message_id'],
        read_at: row['read_at'],
        created_at: row['created_at'],
        updated_at: row['updated_at'],
        message_attributes: {
          id: row['message_id'],
          text: row['text'],
          ...
        }
      )
    end
  end
```

For instance if I have a Message with id=1, two users with id=20 and id=21, and one Notification with (id=30, message_id=1, recipient_id=20), for user 21 and message 1 I get a "virtual" notification with `read_at=nil` (as the user hasn't read it yet) and associated message data

```rb
> User.find(21).notifications

=> [#<Notification:0x00007fb5c64df138 id: nil, message_id: 1, recipient_id: 21, read_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]

> User.find(21).notifications.first.message

=> #<Message:0x00007fd57c52b5a8 id: 1, text: ...>
```

However:

1. It is very verbose and the code needs to be updated whenever a new attribute is added to `Message` or `Notification` for instance;
2. I am not sure of the performance (I think it is fine as everything is already loaded in a single query, I don't think there is an N+1 problem for instance);
3. Most importantly, I would really prefer to achieve the same using a `has_many :notifications` association on `User`, or if not possible, using a custom `notifications` scope. This is in order to avoid eager-loading, to have a more fluent API, to be able to join with other possible relations, etc. Or at least I would like to improve the syntax somehow to be more Rails-like.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just fetch all the rows from the messages and include/eager load the notifications with a condition on the user id? Both includes and eager loads do outer joins so they will return rows from messages even if no rows are found in notifications. It feels like you're starting off the wrong end if what you want is a list of the messages and an indication if the user has read them or not.

Comment: It sounds like notifications are really `read_receipts`.  Typically those don't stick around longer than 30 days in most systems, would that help w/ performance?

Comment: @max Thanks, I tried adding `has_many :notifications` to `Message`, but then `Message.left_outer_joins(:notifications).where(notifications: { recipient_id: 21 })` returns an empty result. Also, loading from the Message side is a good idea but I am still not entirely decided on the modelling. I might keep the message info in the Notification model and rename Message to Announcement, like in https://github.com/excid3/jumpstart/tree/master/app/models. This is to be more flexible with messages which do not target all users but only some. So anyway I would be interested to a solution to both cases.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks, optionally indeed it would be even better to load the data in such a way where messages older than X days are automatically shown as read, without needing to create the corresponding notifications (or `read_receipts` as you proposed to call them).

Comment: I realized that includes / eager load is not really going to work so I'll rehrase. What you want is to select the rows off messages and select `notifications.read_at`. There are a ton of ways of doing this like for example subqueries: `Message.left_joins(:notifications).select('messages.*', ['(SELECT 1 FROM notifications n WHERE id.message_id = messages.id AND n.user_id  = ?) AS read_by_user',  user.id])`. On Postgres you can use lateral joins.

Comment: @max I adapted your proposal as follows: `Message.left_joins(:notifications).select('messages.*', ['(SELECT read_at FROM notifications n WHERE n.message_id = messages.id AND n.recipient_id = ?) AS read_at', 21]).first`. However it gives a syntax error on the question mark. If I hard-code the value, it works fine. Would you know any place where this `select` syntax is better documented?

Comment: OK this seems to work: `Message.select('messages.*', ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql(['(SELECT read_at FROM notifications n WHERE n.message_id = messages.id AND n.recipient_id = ?) AS read_at', user.id]))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the notifications that belong to the user. Then retrieve the messages that that don't have a notification for the target user and build a notification for them. Lastly combine the two collections.

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notifications
end

class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notifications # you might need `inverse_of: :recipient`

  def all_notifications
    notifications.load + Message
      .where.not(id: notifications.pluck(:message_id)).pluck(:id)
      .map { |message_id| notifications.build(message_id: message_id) }
  end
end
```

Sadly this does still produce an array result. I'm not sure a normal association for this is possible. Let's hope that some other answer proves me wrong.

I do want to ask you if this produces the correct results? The question is quite complex and I'm not sure if my understanding of it is a 100% correct.

Comment: Yes, this solves point 1: code is much more concise. It does not solve point 2: all messages get loaded then notifications for each message get loaded separately. Nor point 3: doesn't operate at the level of ActiveRecord association. The result does appear correct (same as with my own code).

Comment: I've updated the answer and this should largely resolve point 2. There are now only 2 SQL statements executed. The first to fetch the notifications already present. The second one only retrieves the message ids for missing message notifications. Issue 3 still stands.